# Python replace specific numbers in a file without change other numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, replace

I have text files which look like this (much longer, this is just some lines from it):

```
ATOM      6  H2  ACD Z   1      47.434  34.593  -4.121   1.000
ATOM      7  C   ACT Z   2      47.465  33.050  -2.458   1.000
ATOM      8  O   ACT Z   2      48.004  33.835  -1.687   1.000
ATOM      9  CH1 ACT Z   2      47.586  33.197  -3.960   1.000
ATOM     79  H1  EOL Z  14      46.340  32.495   2.495   1.000
ATOM     80  C1  PHN Z  15      46.992  33.059  -2.874   1.000
ATOM     81  C2  PHN Z  15      46.876  32.765  -1.499   1.000
ATOM     82  C3  PHN Z  15      46.836  31.422  -1.079   1.000
```

In the 6. "column" I have to change all of the numbers to 1, without changing the other numbers. I tried to define a function but it doesn't work (replace_numbers). This means that the script runs and everything is ok just the numbers don't change.
Here is an example what I want:

```
ATOM      6  H2  LIG Z   1      47.434  34.593  -4.121   1.000
ATOM      7  C   LIG Z   1      47.465  33.050  -2.458   1.000
ATOM      8  O   LIG Z   1      48.004  33.835  -1.687   1.000
ATOM      9  CH1 LIG Z   1      47.586  33.197  -3.960   1.000
ATOM     79  H1  LIG Z   1      46.340  32.495   2.495   1.000
ATOM     80  C1  LIG Z   1      46.992  33.059  -2.874   1.000
ATOM     81  C2  LIG Z   1      46.876  32.765  -1.499   1.000
ATOM     82  C3  LIG Z   1      46.836  31.422  -1.079   1.000
```

I copy my whole script. Comments are in Hungarian.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import re


# en kodom
molecules = {"ETH":"LIG", "EOL":"LIG", "THS":"LIG", "BUT":"LIG", "ACN":"LIG",
             "AMN":"LIG", "DFO":"LIG", "DME":"LIG", "BDY":"LIG", "BEN":"LIG",
             "CHX":"LIG", "PHN":"LIG", "ACD":"LIG", "ACT":"LIG", "ADY":"LIG",
             "URE":"LIG"}
numbers = {x: '1' for x in range(1, 50)}

def replace_numbers(i):
    i_list = i.split()
    if i_list[0] == "ATOM":
        i_list[5] = '1      '
        i_list[0] = i_list[0] + '      '
        i_list[1] = i_list[1] + '  '
        i_list[2] = i_list[2] + '  '
        i_list[3] = i_list[3] + ' '
        i_list[4] = i_list[4] + '   '
        i_list[6] = i_list[6] + '  '
        i_list[7] = i_list[7] + '  '
        i_list[8] = i_list[8] + '   '
        i = ''.join(i_list)
        return i


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for z, zs in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(z, zs)
    return text
# en kodom end

def split_file(f, n, dirname):
    data = f.readlines() # az input fajl minden sorat olvassa es listat csinal a sorokbol
    concat_data = "".join(data) # egy olyan szoveget ad vissza ami a data-bol all
    split_data = concat_data.split("HEADER ") # felbontja a concat_data-t, a hatarolojel a HEADER - nincs benne
    header = "" 
    result = []
    for i in split_data:
        if i.startswith("protein"):
            header = i
        if i.startswith("crosscluster"):
            crs_cluster_num = int(re.findall(r"crosscluster\.\d*\.(\d*)\.pdb", i)[0])
                # ez hogy csinalja amit csinal?
            if crs_cluster_num > 16:
                #en kodom
                i = replace_all(i, molecules)
                i = replace_numbers(i)

                #en kodom end
                result.append(i) # hozzaadja a result nevu listahoz

    for output in result:
        with open(str(dirname) + "_output"+str(n)+".pdb","w") as out_file: # az aoutput nevet es helyet adja meg
            out_file.write("HEADER " + header) # hozzaadja a HEADER-t es beirja a proteint
            out_file.write("HEADER " + output) # hozzaadja a HEADER szoveget illetve proteineket egyesevel
            out_file.write("#PROTEINTAG\n#PROBETAG ZYXWVUTSR") # hozzaadja az utolso sorokat a vegehez
            out_file.close()
            n += 1 # ?

    return n


if __name__ == "__main__": # ?
    n = 1
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/home/georgina/proba"):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = str(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            print dirname
            if filename.endswith(".pdb"):
                file_to_split = open(file_path, "r") # megnyitja a szetbontando fajlt
                n = split_file(file_to_split, n, dirname) # a split_file funkcio behivasa
                file_to_split.close()
```

I tried this with regular expression, with same result.

```
def replace_numbers(text):
    expr = re.compile(r'(LIG )([A-Z])\s*\d*(\s*)')
    expr.sub(r'\1\2  1,\3', text)
    return text
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Do you need to maintain all that spacing? Please include an example of your desired output.

Comment: The script runs, files appear just the number changing function doesn't appear. And yes, I need that the output look like exatly as the input, "columns" can't move.

Answer (score 1):

Since the columns have fixed width, it's easier if you don't split the line:

```
def replace_numbers(line):
    if line[:4] == 'ATOM'
        line = line[:24] + ' 1      ' + line[32:]
    return line
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly when there is a number > 10, the columns will move I think

Comment: The columns won't move, because you are replacing `line[25:32]` with `1` plus the correct number of spaces. It doesn't matter if that whole space is filled with numbers.

Comment: I saw your edit; so the column you want to replace starts one character to the left of what I thought. My edit should take care of that. In any case, you solved the problem, so it's all good. The only issue I have with your solution is that it's not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just figured it out (with some help) xD Thanks for the answer. :)

```
def replace_numbers(text):
    expr = re.compile(r'(LIG )([A-Z])\s*\d*(\s*)')
    text = expr.sub(r'\1\2  1\3', text)
    return text
```

This is works.